# ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to implement AI smart mirror project on raspberry pi3.. i have been stuck here for a long time.. i want to use camera microphone as a voice input source but i cannot.. if someone could help!?
these are the errors while i run my python file

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: 
Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: 
Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
I'm listening
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 254, in 
bot.start()
File "bot.py", line 43, in start
recognizer, audio = self.speech.listen_for_audio()
File "/home/pi/mirror/speech.py", line 37, in listen_for_audio
audio = r.listen(source)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/init.py", 
line 559, in listen
buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/init.py", 
line 161, in read
return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
```

Comment: This can get rid of some of the messages: `sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and comment out `cards.pcm.{device}` where `{device}` is the unknown devices listed